# CSS Elements positioning using relative and absolute

Tags: css

I am trying to **position** the elements using 'absolute' and 'relative' in CSS, I am also using 'padding' and 'margin' to position but my entire *card* elements is messed up. here is the code:

- relative
- absolute
- margin
- padding

```css
    .side3_style {
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .side3-dp img {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 4px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        float: left;
    }
    .side3-info {
        display: inline-block;
        top: 4px;
    }

    .side3-name {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #3b3b3b;
        font-weight: bold;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .user3-time {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', Sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #9D9D9D;
    }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsXS2.png)

Comment: Create fiddle using https://jsfiddle.net/ and put your html and css code.

Comment: you need to clear the float

Comment: @aviboy2006 NEVER ask someone to do that! Code is to be presented, here, within the question, and not any third party site. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you have a root div 'A' where you set position: relative and then inside this div you place another div 'B' with position absolute.

```
<div id="A" style="position: relative"><div id="B" style="position: absolute; top: 100px;left:100px;"></div></div>
```

If you check the above code, you will see that div B will be placed ^ 100px top distance from div A, and < 100px left distance from div A wherever div A exists.

Moreover you have to be carefull if you use float css attribute because you cannot then position based on parent elements easily.

I hope this helps

Comment: thank you Man! this is nice,  I will position again the elements using padding, nice!

Comment: @Patrick if you like the answer you can vote it up